# Problems with 'lambda' expression in python

Tags: python, syntax

I have the following problem solving question

> Please write a program using generator to print the even numbers
>   between  0 and n in comma separated form while n is input by console.
>
> Example: If the following n is given as input to the program: 10 Then,
>   the output of the program should be: 0,2,4,6,8,10.

And below is my answer

```
n=int(input("enter the number of even numbers needed:"))
eve=''
st=(lambda x:(for i in range(0,x))[(str(i)) if i%2==0 else (",")])(n)
```

However, I have a problem with the third line that has the lambda

Comment: I know I can make use of the regular functions, but I wanted to get it done using lambda and am hence stuck.

Comment: please add more details, what is the output you are getting for instance, it is not clear what you are asking here

Comment: You can't write a `for` loop in a `lambda` function. They are limited to a single expression.

Comment: Hint: use `','.join` to create the comma-separated string of numbers.

Comment: `lambda x: (f"{i}," for i in range(0, x + 1, 2))` does create a **generator**. You don't need a function that uses the `yield` statement. Take a look at my answer @SashankPisupati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take full advantage of Python 3's features to create a generator using generator expression syntax, also do the even number stepping with `range()`'s third paramter.

This would be much briefer:

```
>>> n = 12
>>> 
>>> fn = lambda x: (f"{i}," for i in range(0, x + 1, 2))
>>> 
>>> ''.join(list(fn(n)))[:-1] + '.'
'0,2,4,6,8,10,12.'
>>> 
>>> fn(10)
<generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x107f67660>
```

What looks like a tuple comprehension is actually called a "generator expression".  Note that in the last line above the interpeter is indicating that the type returned by the lambda is indeed a generator.

Even briefer, you could do it this way:

```
>>> fn = lambda x: ','.join(  (f"{i}" for i in range(0, x + 1, 2))  ) + '.'
>>> 
>>> fn(n)
'0,2,4,6,8,10,12.'
>>>
```

Looks like you might have been on the right track in your question post.

A function that uses the `yield` keyword also creates a generator. So the other poster is correct in that regard.

Comment: if you don't mind could you please explain what role does f"{i}" play here?

Comment: yes. That's called a 'string interpolation'. When you put an `f` in front of a string, the interpreter evaluates anything in between curly braces `{...}` as Python code, and inserts that in-place in the string. It's a "f-string".. so `f"{i}"` tells the interp to evaluate the variable `i` and insert it in the string at its position. Alternatively, I could have just put str(i) there.